# Complex Potential describing inviscid fluid flow

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, flow, complex-numbers

I'm a Mathematics student, working through a homework sheet for a Fluid Mechanics module. The question is given:

> Consider the flow described by the complex potential $$w=4z+\frac{8}{z}.$$
>
> 1. Determine $\psi$, $\phi$, $u$ and $v$ in plane polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$.
> 2. Determine the location of the stagnation points.
> 3. Show that this complex potential describes an inviscid flow around a solid, *finite* object, What is the shape of the object?
> 4. Sketch the streamlines for the flow outside the object.

My working out so far for the question is:

(1) Let $z=re^{i\theta}$, and therefore

\begin{align} 
w&=4re^{i\theta}+\frac{8}{r}e^{-i\theta} \\
&=4r(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))+\frac{8}{r}(\cos(\theta)-i\sin(\theta)) \\
&=(4r+\frac{8}{r})\cos(\theta)+(4r-\frac{8}{r})i\sin(\theta).
\end{align}

Using the Cauchy-Riemann equtaions, $w=\phi+i\psi$, we then have that $\phi=(4r+\frac{8}{r})\cos(\theta)$ and $\psi=(4r-\frac{8}{r})\sin(\theta)$.

Also, we have that $u=\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial r}\implies u=(4-8r^{-2})\cos(\theta)$ and $v=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\theta} \implies v=-(4r+8r^{-2})\sin(\theta)$.

(2) Stagnation points are given by $u=0$ and $v=0$. So, from $u=0$, we have that $r^2=2$ or $\cos(\theta)=0$. Similarly from $v=0$, we have that $r^2=-2$ and $\sin(\theta)=0$. Therefore, the stagnation points occur at $(r,\theta)=(\sqrt{2},0),(\sqrt{2},\pi)$.

From here (ie (3) onwards), I fall down. I think that I should use that $\textbf{u}\cdot\textbf{n}=0$, but I'm not too sure how to use this information. Should I be using Bernoulli's theorem for pressure? Is there some assumption I am missing?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Since this is a mathematical question, we need to move the topic to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Trounev's answer. You already found the stagnation points at $(r,\theta)=(\sqrt{2},0)$ and $(\sqrt{2},\pi)$. Since there are two stagnation points we anticipate a *finite* solid body (in contrast, [Rankine half body](http://www-mdp.eng.cam.ac.uk/web/library/enginfo/aerothermal_dvd_only/aero/fprops/poten/node35.html) has one stagnation point and is semi-infinite). The streamfunction $\psi$ evaluates to zero at both stagnation points, which implies that $\psi=0$ streamline connects them. A finite solid body is formed by a closed streamline; if $r=\sqrt{2}$ then the value of the streamline connecting the two stagnation points remains the same (equal to zero) for any $\theta$, which implies that it is closed. Therefore the finite solid body you seek (which is the streamline $\psi=0$) is a circle of radius $\sqrt{2}$. This approach is more general than Trounev's; he begins by assuming that the body is a circle (by assuming that the normal $\mathbf{n}$ to the solid body is the unit radial vector) which assumption is then shown to be consistent from the ensuing result; however his procedure wouldn't work for a body of arbitrary shape, say an ellipse.

P.S. The question should have clarified that the body sought for is *finite*. Otherwise any pair of distinct streamlines can be taken as the boundary of a solid body because $\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{n}=0$ is satisfied on every streamline.

Comment: I discussed the question with my lecturer after posting this, and he advised me to use $\textbf{u}\cdot\textbf{n}=0$, rather than the streamlines and streamfunction. Also, we haven't considered not finite bodies in class, which perhaps I should have made clear in my question, so I did not even think it would be an option (will edit).

Comment: @Fats The problem is that you don't know ahead of time what $\mathbf{n}$ is (the shape of the body isn't given, I presume) and must be guessed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's pretend that this potential describes inviscid  flow around cylinder with radius $r=\sqrt {2}$. We have $u = (4 - 8/r^2)\cos {\theta},v = -(4 + 8/r^2)\sin {\theta}$.  Using the no-flow condition on the surface of a solid object $\vec {u}.\vec {n}=0$ we find $(u,v).(1,0)=0$, and from here we get $u=0$, and $r=\sqrt {2}$. Therefore, it is proven.  To build the streamlines, I used the standard program from Mathematica 11.3. For this, the field $(u,v)$ has been converted to Cartesian coordinates. To make sure that this is a 2D flow, and not 3D, we calculate the divergence of the velocity field: $\nabla .\vec {u}=0$ in 2D, and $\nabla .\vec {u}=-16z/(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2$  in 3D. Therefore it is 2D flow.
[image: fig1]

Comment: Can the object be a sphere? Why are we sure that it is a cylinder?

Comment: @Fats First, correct the typo in your topic should be $v=-(4+8/r^2)\sin {\theta }$. Second, calculate the divergence in 2D and in 3D, should be $\nabla .\vec {u}=0$. See update to my answer.

Comment: @ Alex Trounev: Is the complex potential even defined for a 3D flow?

Comment: @D.Halsey Axisymmetric flow around a sphere is also described in coordinates $r, \theta $.  It looks like a 2D. Apparently so there was a question for Fats.

Comment: No one understood the solution, but they vote down:)